# Delay when Copy or Cut in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

When I press CTRL+X in Visual Studio there's a small delay and the IDE hangs for about 1 second.

I've already checked Environment/Keyboard and the shortcut is assign to Edit.Cut as it's supposed to...

The system was functioning properly and only started to get this situation a few days ago.

What can this be and how can I try to figure out the root of the problem?

EDIT:
Figure out that the problem is not the shortcuts but when I do cut or copy. When pasting there's no delay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because of the high usage of memory and the unnecessary resources that is running. Try restarting your computer and see what happens :) cheers!

Comment: Restarting the machine resolved the problem. The oldest problem solver solution... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Open up a Task Manager window, and in the Processes tab, sort it by the CPU column. When you copy, check which process is using the CPU.

If it's Visual Studio itself then maybe a [Reset Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241273.aspx) would fix it (although annoying to do).
If it's something else then at least you have a clue/starting point.

Comment: It was curious because Task Manager also freezed. Meanwhile I've restarted the machine and it resolved the problem. Thank you for your input.